# ngStyle function run on conditional

Tags: angular

I have a list of css styles that I wish to load via ngStyle and a function within ngStyle. However I only want the function to run if a value is true and not to run at all if it is not. I know I could run the function and return a null value but using the correct markup I could save on the need to run it.

I have been doing the conditional logic in the function.

```
<h2[ngStyle]="setStyles(h2)">H2 Content</h2>

<h5[ngStyle]="setStyles(h5)">H5 Content</h2>
```

in the .ts file I have

```
let ifPrint = true;

let style = {
   'h2' : {'font-size' : '16px', 'font-weight' : '600'},
   'h5' : {'font-size' : '12px', 'font-weight' : '400'},
   'default' : {}
  }

setStyles(tag){
return ifPrint ? style[tag] : style['default']; 
)};
```

I want something like

`<h2[ngStyle]="ifPrint ? setStyles(h2) : noneedtorunfunction ">H2 Content</h2>`

What do I need to place in the noneedtorunfunction to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

**component.ts**

```
ifPrint: boolean;

setStyles(tag) {
  return {
     ['h2'] : {'font-size' : '44px', 'font-weight' : '600'},
     ['h5'] : {'font-size' : '12px', 'font-weight' : '400'},
     ['default']: {}, 
 }[tag];
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h2 [ngStyle]="ifPrint ? setStyles('h2') : '' ">H2 Content</h2>
```

When `ifPrint` is false, the style attribute will be empty.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Declare this as a global variable. Then `ifPrint` being true or false will toggle the font size.

**Controller**

```
  public style = {
   'h2' : {'font-size' : '44px', 'font-weight' : '600'},
   'h5' : {'font-size' : '12px', 'font-weight' : '400'}
  };
```

**Template**

```
<h2 [ngStyle]="ifPrint ? style['h2'] : null">H2 Content</h2>
```

I think this is what you are looking for, or the closest I can get it.

Comment: Thanks but can I not just include something so that the function does not run at all if the condition is not met. I thought at empty object but that won't work. That is the basis of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to resolve this is extract your style to scss/css file, and your component you can call the class that you set in scss/css file.

*** In Component ***

```
setStyle(tag: string): string {
  return {
     ['h2'] : 'h2-class',
     ['h5'] : 'h5-class'
  }
}
```